# Collection.Add: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub that creates a `Collection` and adds `Collection`s inside it. But I get an `Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment` error when adding a first collection in the loop:

```
Sub testState()
    Dim stateCopy As State
    Set stateCopy = New State
    stateCopy.setStateName="some name"
    stateCopy.storeBudgetWorkbooks
    stateCopy.storeBudgetDatas  'error on this line
End Sub

Sub storeBudgetDatas()  'inside a class named State
 ...
  Dim year As Integer
  Dim i As Integer
  i = 1
  For year = 2014 To 2017
      Set budgetWorkbook = 
          ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Open(budgetWorkbooks(i))
      MsgBox ("still here")  'this message appears

      allBudgetItems.Add getBudgetData(budgetWorkbook, year) 'this line is likely to cause problems


      MsgBox ("and here")  'this message doesn't appear
      budgetWorkbook.Close
      i = i + 1
  Next
End Sub

Function getBudgetData(budgetWorkbook As Workbook, year As Integer)
  ...
  Dim budgetItems As Collection
  Set budgetItems = getBudgetItems(year)
  ... 'setting attributes
  getBudgetData = budgetItems(year)
End Function

Function getBudgetItems(year As Integer)
  ...
  Dim resultCollection As Collection
  Set resultCollection = New Collection
  Dim itemCopy As Item
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = LBound(budgetItemNames) To UBound(budgetItemNames)
      Set itemCopy = New Item
      ... 'setting attributes
      resultCollection.Add itemCopy
  Next

  Set getBudgetItems = resultCollection
End Function
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here. `getBudgetItems` returns a collection. `getBudgetData` returns a collection as well. I tried adding/removing parenthesis but to no avail.

Comment: Your code is not complete, so you may find help less forthcoming. The Sub storeBudgetWorkbooks is missing and what is allBudgetItems Dimmed as are obvious issues...

Comment: Have you stepped into the class code using f8 (or set your VBE to break in class modules) to locate the actual problem line?

Comment: @Rory, What do you mean by this? I don't know how to find out the actual problem like, it just highlights the line with the function call, not a specific line inside the function.

Comment: If you press f8 after pressing Debug, does the debugger step into the class code or not?

Comment: Presumably `budgetWorkbooks` is another function within your class? If so, can you check if `budgetWorkbook` has been set as a workbook before you call `getBudgetData`?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. There should have been `Set getBudgetData = budgetItems(year)` instead of `getBudgetData = budgetItems(year)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't shown us all the relevant parts of your code, the best I can do is guess you're missing a `Set`:

```
Function getBudgetData(budgetWorkbook As Workbook, year As Integer)
  ...
  Dim budgetItems As Collection
  Set budgetItems = getBudgetItems(year)
  ... 'setting attributes
  Set getBudgetData = budgetItems(year) ' Need Set here
End Function
```